# javascript magically inserting an empty var into a new array / changing its length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, insert, var

So i have a piece of code like this:

```
this.convertParametersToGroups = function (nodes) {

        self.selectedParametersGroup([]);
        var emptyParametersList = [];

        var pos = 0;
        var group;
        var tempParametersGroup = [];         
                            // tempParametersGroup: Array[1]
                            // 0: undefined   

        $.each(nodes, function (key, val) {
            emptyParametersList.push(0);
            group = self.convertNodeToParameterGroup(val);
            group.position = pos;
            tempParametersGroup.push(group);
            pos++;
        });

        self.selectedParametersGroup(tempParametersGroup);

        return emptyParametersList;
    };
```

The commented results don't change when I reorder the declarations.
When i had "group" in an $.each loop, it inserted an undefined value in the first iteration, before executing the first statement in the callback.

However, when I change their names around like this:

```
this.convertParametersToGroups = function (nodes) {

        self.selectedParametersGroup([]);
        var emptyParametersList = [];

        var pos = 0;
        var g;
        var tempParametersGr = [];         
                            // tempParametersGr: Array[0]

        $.each(nodes, function (key, val) {
            emptyParametersList.push(0);
            g = self.convertNodeToParameterGroup(val);
            g.position = pos;
            tempParametersGr.push(g);
            pos++;
        });

        self.selectedParametersGroup(tempParametersGr);

        return emptyParametersList;
    };
```

It works as in comments. Seems like javascript somehow maps the "group" name to the "Group" suffix of the array and inserts it or forces length increment. Am I missing some known language feature or...?

Comment: Please show the relevant code, `group` is not special keyword and the results in both snippets are equivalent.

Comment: JS never "magically" does anything.  Show some more of your code.

Comment: It just highlights the word for some reason, it's a name of a variable. This is in every way the relevant code.

Comment: @StefanZimecki I can assure you, it isn't.

Comment: @StefanZimecki no this code is boring, you set a variable to undefined and then set another variable to empty array. Then you do it again. What you have in comments doesn't represent the actual results so the code isn't relevant.

Comment: Okay, added the whole function. What's in the comments is copied over from Chrome's inspector after respective instructions.

Comment: @StefanZimecki how are you logging the arrays?

Comment: @Esailija can you please explain what do you mean by logging? I'm pretty new to js.

Comment: @StefanZimecki I mean, where in the code you assert that `var tempParametersGroup = []; // tempParametersGroup: Array[1] // 0: undefined`. Because the way you are doing it, is not correct if it says it's an `Array[1]`

Comment: @Esailija As i said it's just a copied watch value from Chrome debugger. It says that it has one undefined element.

Comment: Right, if you want the absolute truth about what the state of `tempParametersGroup` is after `var tempParametersGroup = [];`,
add a line right below it that says: `console.log( JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( tempParametersGroup ) ) );`

Comment: @Esailija it seems like stringifying and parsing cuts out the undefined value. The last call before return updates a databinding and throws an exception because of the undefined value.

Comment: @StefanZimecki it doesn't affect the original array in any way, it simply `clones` it and logs it so we can get absolute truth about its state at the time of logging. That is, to proove that the comment is incorrect. In your second snippet you have `tempParametersGroup.push(g);` though that variable doesn't exist in that snippet.

Comment: @Esailija sorry, mistake while editing, don't have the two versions written at the moment. I don't mean it affects it - I mean that the output of either of those two functions ignores undefined values. One way or another, it's still there

Comment: @StefanZimecki sure, but not at the time of creating the array. You may use this logging technique to determine exactly when it was added to the array.

Comment: @Esailija I'm using it directly after the definition and the results differ from the debugger watches. After the loop the array still contains the undefined element before all others, so I assume it's added on creation despite the empty initialization.

Comment: @StefanZimecki Don't use the debugger watches if they are this counterproductive. A freshly created array with `[]` will simply not have any elements inside it, undefined or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try debugging this way, it should be very clear when the undefined was actually added to the array:

```
function makeClone( arr ) {
    return JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( arr ) );
}

this.convertParametersToGroups = function (nodes) {

        self.selectedParametersGroup([]);
        var emptyParametersList = [];

        var pos = 0;
        var group;
        var tempParametersGroup = [];

        console.log( "before loop", makeClone( tempParametersGroup ) );


        $.each(nodes, function (key, val) {
            console.log( "before iteration", key, makeClone( tempParametersGroup ) );
            emptyParametersList.push(0);
            group = self.convertNodeToParameterGroup(val);
            group.position = pos;
            tempParametersGroup.push(group);
            pos++;
            console.log( "after iteration", key, makeClone( tempParametersGroup ) );
        });

        console.log( "after loop", makeClone( tempParametersGroup ) );

        self.selectedParametersGroup(tempParametersGroup);

        return emptyParametersList;
    };
```